# Не могу сделать телеграмм бота который выводит рандомное число и добавляет его в базу данных python aiogram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, случайные-числа, aiogram, peewee

Мне нужен Telegram Bot на Python(Aiogram) который выводит рандомное число и добавляет его в БД(ORM PEEWEE). Бот должен выводит сообщение в котором это число и то число которое в БД, то есть при каждом вызове команды бот выводит сообщение с рандомным числом и каждый раз добавляет это рандомное число к тому числу которое в БД и выводит то число из БД в том же сообщении.

Файл main.py

```
import logging

from peewee import Update
import config

from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
from cmnd import *
from models import User

bot = Bot(token=config.TOKEN)

dp = Dispatcher(bot)

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

@dp.message_handler(commands="start")
async def cmd_start(message: types.Message):
    u, is_created = User.get_or_create(
        tg_id=message.from_user.id,
        defaults={
            'username': message.from_user.username
        })
    await message.answer("СТАРТ.")

@dp.message_handler(commands="test")
async def cmd_test(message: types.Message):
    u  = User.update(
        tg_id=message.from_user.id,
        test_sm=rndm
        ).execute
    await message.reply("Твоя на " + rndm + " см. Теперь твоя " + sm + " см. Поздравляю!")





if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Запуск бота
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

Файл cmnd.py

```
import random

from models import User

rndm = str(random.randint(1, 10))

sm = str(User.get(User.test_sm == 0))
```

Файл models.py

```
from peewee import Model, CharField, IntegerField, DateTimeField
from config import DB

from datetime import datetime


class BaseModel(Model):
    class Meta:
        database = DB


class User(BaseModel):
    tg_id = IntegerField()
    username = CharField()
    registered = DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    test_sm = IntegerField(default=0)
    

# Создание таблиц
DB.create_tables([User, ])
```

Comment: В чём состоит сложность? Когда поступает запрос от пользователя 1) сгенерировать новое число. 2) достать из бд прежнее. 3) сложить. 4)записать новое в бд. 5) отправить пользователю нужное.

Comment: Проблема в том что рандомное число не добавляется в БД и не выводит его в сообщение.

Comment: Тогда код прикрепите, используя функцию "Править" у вопроса.

Comment: Я прикрепил, можете смотреть

Comment: **rndm и sm** нужно по новой получать в **cmd_test** каждый раз. В данном случае, предполагаю, единожды сохранилось всё и не вызывается по новой ни **random.randint(1, 10)**, ни **User.get(User.test_sm == 0)**

Comment: И как мне правильно написать код чтобы оно работало как надо?

Answer (score 0):

По-видимому, проблема в том, что в модуле **cmnd.py** единоразово происходит инициализация переменных **rndm** и **sm**. Следует вызывать эти функции и инициализировать переменные при каждом вызове команды пользователем.

Предполагаю, что нужно это делать как-то так:

```
@dp.message_handler(commands="test")
async def cmd_test(message: types.Message):
    import random
    
    # так при каждом вызове будет генерироваться новое число
    rndm = str(random.randint(1, 10))
    # и будет выполняться запрос к бд для получения свежих данных
    u = User.get(User.tg_id = message.from_user.id)
        
    sm = str(u.test_sm)
    
    # потом обновляем данные пользователя
    User.update(tg_id=message.from_user.id, test_sm=rndm).execute()
    
    # возвращаем ответ пользователю
    await message.reply("Твоя на " + rndm + " см. Теперь твоя " + sm + " см. Поздравляю!")
```

Comment: Полагаю, импорт модуля `random` лучше сделать в самом верху, а не в функции.

Comment: Вероятно так, но это тоже вопрос спорный и не столь существенный. Я привёл минимальный код, для ответа на вопрос.

Comment: Мне выбевает ошибку: raise self.model.DoesNotExist('%s instance matching query does '
models.UserDoesNotExist: <Model: User> instance matching query does not exist:
SQL: SELECT "t1"."id", "t1"."tg_id", "t1"."username", "t1"."registered", "t1"."test_sm" FROM "user" AS "t1" WHERE ("t1"."test_sm" = ?) LIMIT ? OFFSET ?
Params: [530010423, 1, 0]

Comment: Создание пользователя у вас происходит при вызове команды `/start`. Если же вы хотите вызывать сразу `/test`, то используйте  `get_or_create()` вместо `get()`.

Comment: Я сначала вызываю команду /start, а уже потом /test но ошибка всьо равно есть.

Comment: Тогда в /start методе добавь `u.save()` перед отправкой сообщения

Comment: Я добавил но ошибка не исчезла

Comment: В таблице данные появляются? В дебаге смотрел, совпадают ли id, лежащий в таблице и тот, который вытаскиваешь из `message.from_user.id`?

Comment: Да данные появляются

Comment: Что делать нужно чтобы ошибки не было?

Comment: Внёс исправление, внимательно пересмотрел ваш код. Пробуйте ещё раз